# iOS 7,cannot change height for TableHeaderView

Tags: ios, tableview, ios7

```
- (void)reloadUI
{
    [_createNoteView layoutSubviews];
    if (_list.is_archived == 0) {
        _tableview.tableHeaderView = _createNoteView;
    }
    [_tableview reloadData];
}
```

I have a resizable input view called `_createNoteView`,`[_createNoteView layoutSubviews]` will correct its own frame.
each time content of `_createNoteView` was changed `reloadUI` will called.
I expect `_createNoteView will` will resize while I'm typing in it. But things won't work in iOS 7;
Everything works well on iOS 6 with the same context;

Comment: Be more specific while asking questions.

Comment: i'm seeing a similar issue w/ iOS7.  did you find a work around?

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not very much clear, this is a general answer.
Have you used this tableview delegate method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return 60;

}
```

You can calculate the size of header in this method and return the specific height
The previous one is for tableview section's header.

May be this could also help

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
tableView.tableHeaderView = your_headerView;
```